# Does subtracting linearly independent vectors retain linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Say you have a finite set of linearly independent vectors

$\{v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n\}$

Will the following set of their differences also be linearly independent?

$\{v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,...,v_n-v_1\}$

Whether it is $L.I.$ or not, what is the proof?

Comment: They obviously aren't: the sum of all new vectors is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Big thank you to @ivan-neretin for making me come to my senses.

The vectors will definitely not be linearly independent.

The proof is that let's say you have a scalar $k$. You multiply each vector in the second set with $k$. Add these vectors up like so

$k(v_1-v_2)+k(v_2-v_3)+...+k(v_n-v_1)$

Expanding yields

$kv_1-kv_2+kv_2+kv_3+...+kv_n-kv_1$

As you can see, for any $k$, the sum will be zero. The sum being equal to zero is not exclusive to $k=0$ as in linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Why to bother with $k\,$? Isn't this enough: $$1\cdot(v_1-v_2)+1\cdot(v_2-v_3)+\dots+1\cdot(v_n-v_1)$$ is a non-trivial expansion of the zero vector